# iOS Simulator pinch gesture not working

Tags: xcode, ios-simulator

I'm having trouble with the new Xcode simulator. I've looked this question up and got the same answer which won't work for me: Hold Option key and two circles will come up then click and drag. But this doesn't work for me. Only one circle comes up and it disappears when clicked. I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong!

Comment: What happens when you move your mouse cursor without clicking? In my iOS simulator, two circles appear when I hold down option; but they sometimes overlap, which makes it look as though there's only one circle. The circles will disappear if you complete a full click (depress and release the mouse button). Holding down the mouse button simulates a pinch gesture for me.